# is there a way to get realtime permession access by an app on rooted android phone?

Tags: android, logging, kernel, android-permissions, android-log

I'm trying to get all the permission of 3rd party apps in real time. I can get static permissions from the manifest file but want to know is it possible to obtain live permission access from other apps. is it possible to get from the system log files?

Answer (score 0):

XPrivacy is a tool which is able to inform you about permissions asked by any app on your device. You can allow the permission or deny it. It's more of a privacy tool but it can show you permissions of any app currently running.

If you plan on installing XPrivacy, you better use this [installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.bokhorst.xprivacy.installer)